# Update ID value to format XXXXXXXX-X using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Table name: TEST
Column name: ID [VARCHAR(200)]

The format of ID is `‘XXXXXXXX-X’`, where `‘X’` is a number from 0 to 9.
Additional operations in case above format is not satisfied:

1. if the ID consists of 9 digits and there is a double dash between eighth and ninth digit , the extra dash is removed (e.g. 08452142--6 -> 08452142-6)
2. if the ID consists of 9 digits and there is/are space(s) between eighth and ninth digit and/or non-digits and/or non-letter symbol(s) then replace them to dash (e.g. 08452142 - .   3 -> 08452142-3)
3. if the ID consists 9 digits and starts/ends with non-digits and/or non-letter symbol(s) then delete that symbol(s) up to digit (e.g. 08452142-2.. -> 08452142-2)
4. if the ID contains only 9 digits then put a dash before the last digit (e.g. 123456789 -> 12345678-9)

I have achieved the necessary format by using the below snippet.

```
UPDATE TEST
  SET ID = (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ID,'^\d{8}-\d{1}$','') AS "ID" 
            from TEST 
            WHERE PK = 11;
)
```

What are the possible ways to add transformations as mentioned in points[1-4] above in a single query?

Using REGEXP_REPLACE, I can achieve ID in above format. But in case format is incorrect, and ID needs to be transformed[like removing extra dash, or adding dash in case 9 digits are received] to achieve satisfactory format, how can that be achieved in a single UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, you need to extract 9 digits from your string in the first step. And then 
add a hyphen before the last character. For both steps use `regexp_replace()` function

```
with test(id) as
(
 select '08452142--6'    from dual union all
 select '08452142 - . 3' from dual union all
 select '08452142-2..'   from dual union all
 select '123456789'      from dual union all
 select '1234567890'     from dual
)
select case when length(regexp_replace(id,'(\D)'))=9 then
            regexp_replace(regexp_replace(id,'(\D)'),
                                     '(^[[:digit:]]{8})(.*)([[:digit:]]{1}$)','\1-\3')
       end as id
  from test;

ID
----------
08452142-6
08452142-3
08452142-2
12345678-9
<null>
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/TBFY74047)</kbd>

Comment: Hello @Barbaros,

The regex did not work for strings '..00120792-2..' and '00120792-2..'

I tried to modify the regex by adding (.*) at the start and end of the expression to replace any other characters before and after the string "00120792-2" but it does not work.

Comment: Hi @gooner_psy. There still seems no problem. Consider https://rextester.com/XBPIG18099 please.

Comment: Hello @BarbarosOzhan,
I should have been more clear. In the section where I have posted an answer, I am using regexp_replace inside regexp_like for which it fails the 2 strings mentioned in my comment. Please can you check-
https://rextester.com/QSR97396

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following I think:

```
UPDATE TEST
   SET ID = REGEXP_REPLACE(ID,'^\D*(\d{8})\D*(\d)\D*$','\1-\2')
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ID,'^\D*(\d{8})\D*(\d)\D*$')
```

This way you ignore all non-digit charcters and search for a 8-digit number and then an 1-digit number. Take these 2 numbers and put a single '-' in between.

This is a little more generous as you might need but should work with all your provided examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the first 8 digits, then a hyphen, then the 9th digit:

```
select ( substr(regexp_replace(id, '[^0-9]', ''), 1, 8) ||
         '-' ||
         substr(regexp_replace(id, '[^0-9]', ''), 9, 1)
       )
```

Comment: @saiprasad . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I tried an approach based on the suggestion by @BarbarosÖzhan:

```
with source as (
    select  '02426467--6' id from dual union all
    select  '02426467-6' id from dual union all
    select  '02597718 -- .   3' id from dual union all
    select  '02597718 --dF5 .   3' id from dual union all
    select  '00120792-2..' id from dual union all
    select  '..00120792-2..' id from dual union all
    select  '123456789' id from dual union all
    select  '1234567890' id from dual
)
select
    case
        when regexp_like(id, '\d{8}-\d{1}')
            then id
        else
            case
        when regexp_like(id, '\d{8}-\d{1}')
            then id
        else
            case
                when regexp_count(id, '\d') = 9
                    then
                        case
                            when
                                regexp_like(
                                    regexp_replace(
                                        regexp_replace(
                                            id, '(\d{8}-)(-)(\d{1})', '\1\3' 
                                        ), '(\d{8})([^A-Za-z1-9])(\d{1})', '\1-\3' 
                                    )
                                , '\d{8}-\d{1}')
                                then
                                    regexp_replace(
                                        regexp_replace(
                                            id, '(\d{8}-)(-)(\d{1})', '\1\3' 
                                        ), '(\d{8})([^A-Za-z1-9])(\d{1})', '\1-\3' 
                                    )
                            else id
                        end
                else id
            end
    end id_tr
    from source
```

However, in cases 3 and 4, I cannot get rid of the space, dot and alphabets. I think something wrong with the logic in case length is more than 9. I end with "id" as it is so the result is the same without any modifications. 
Any suggestions to impprove this?